# textarea should give an error in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

this is so that my input comes back and gives me beskede if it is such that there is no content in them, but therein fashion, I want to "textarea" do it together so we had to set a beskede for the visitor the page.

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="kontakt_box">
                <br />
                <label>Navn<br /><input type="text" name="navn" class="new" placeholder="Navn"> <span id="myhint">Angive et navn</span></label><br />
                <label>Efternavn<br /><input type="tel" name="efternavn" class="new" placeholder="Efternavn"> <span id="myhint">Angive et efternavn</span></label><br />
                <label>Email<br /><input type="email" name="email" class="new" placeholder="Email"> <span id="myhint">Angive en e-mail</span></label><br />
                <label>Tekst<br /><textarea name="tekst" cols="35" rows="10" class="new"></textarea></label><br />
                <label><input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" class="new"></label>
            </form>
            <span id="sendt"></span>
            <script src="/indhold/js/kontakt.js"></script>
```

here are my jquery code:

```
    $("input").focus(function () {
  $(this).next("#myhint").css('display','inline').fadeOut(5000);
});

$("form").submit(function() {
  if ($("input").val() == "") {
    $("#myhint").text("Husk indhold!.").show();
    return false;
  }
  $("#sendt").text("Den er blevet sendt videre til Mads Ørnfeldt Andersen").show().fadeOut(6000);
  return true;
});
```

Comment: Not sure I get it, but it looks like that does somewhat the same thing as the HTML5 placeholders that you're already using ?

Comment: Okay I think I mostly understand what you are asking. But not really sure on what you mean here "I want to "textarea" do it together so we had to set a beskede for the visitor the page." ... What do you mean by "do it together"? And is the message displaying on the same page as the form?

Comment: yes but I would rather be 100% sure that the user can not just send such without equal!

Comment: Yes it all will be shown in the same page .. what I want out of this is to get the know the name and surname and email must not be empty, since it must specify them. and if it is such that they are empty, it should not send / create user before all is not empty anymore.